# One to many relationship and ID generation

Tags: java, spring, one-to-many

I have two classes.

Poll.java

```
public class Poll {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "poll_id")
    String pollId;
    String question;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    String endDateTime;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "poll_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "poll_id")
    List<Choice> choices;
}
```

and

Choice.java

```
public class Choice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "choice_id")
    Long choiceId;
    String text;
    Integer votes;
}
```

When I create new polls, the choice_id increments from the last previously created choice_id's number. How can I make choice_id reset its value when a new poll is created?

I tried changing the strategy GenerationType, but that does not seem to affect anything. I am expecting a result like this:

```
[
    {
        "pollId": "MvWRj",
        "question": "poll 2?",
        "endDateTime": "2023-07-09 19:50",
        "choices": [
            {
                **"choiceId": 1,**
                "text": "choice 1",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                **"choiceId": 2,**
                "text": "choice 2",
                "votes": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pollId": "V838D",
        "question": "poll 1?",
        "endDateTime": "2023-07-09 19:50",
        "choices": [
            {
                **"choiceId": 1,**
                "text": "choice 1",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                **"choiceId": 2,**
                "text": "choice 2",
                "votes": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

whereas I get the result like:

```
[
    {
        "pollId": "MvWRj",
        "question": "poll 2?",
        "endDateTime": "2023-07-09 19:50",
        "choices": [
            {
                **"choiceId": 3,**
                "text": "choice 1",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                **"choiceId": 4,**
                "text": "choice 2",
                "votes": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pollId": "V838D",
        "question": "poll 1?",
        "endDateTime": "2023-07-09 19:50",
        "choices": [
            {
                **"choiceId": 1,**
                "text": "choice 1",
                "votes": 1
            },
            {
                **"choiceId": 2,**
                "text": "choice 2",
                "votes": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `Choice` class data will be stored into a table, let's assume `choice` and as you mentioned `choiceId` as `@Id` it is a `primary key`, so it shouldn't have duplicate values

Comment: if you want to have 1, 2, 3 ... for each new poll, you can introduced a **new** column into `choice` table and use that when saving the `poll` record

Comment: @kcsurapaneni What if I were to use "choice_id" and "poll_id_fk" as a composite primary key?

Comment: in `choice` table? yeah, you can do that, but remember you have to update `Choice` entity accordingly and I'm not sure about auto generating one of the key in case of composite primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the behavior you're looking for – where `choiceId` resets for each new `Poll` – you will need to make some changes to your current implementation. The primary issue is that `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` in your `Choice` class generates a unique identifier for every `Choice` entity across all `Poll` entities, resulting in incrementing IDs across different polls.

Here are a few approaches you might consider:

#### 1. Manual ID Management

You could manually manage the `choiceId` instead of using `@GeneratedValue`. This approach would require you to set the `choiceId` for each `Choice` relative to its `Poll` when creating or adding choices to a poll. However, this can get complex and error-prone, especially with concurrent transactions.

#### 2. Composite Key

Consider using a composite key that includes both the `pollId` and an additional identifier for each choice. This way, the `choiceId` could be unique only within the scope of each `Poll`. The composite key can be implemented using `@Embeddable` or `@EmbeddedId` in JPA.

Example of a composite key class:

```java
@Embeddable
public class ChoiceId implements Serializable {
    private String pollId;
    private Long choiceNumber; // This resets for each Poll

    // getters, setters, hashCode, equals
}
```

In your `Choice` class, you would use `ChoiceId` as the primary key.

#### 3. Database-Level Solution

If your database supports it, you could use a database-specific feature that allows for resetting sequence numbers based on a condition (like the creation of a new `Poll`). This is database-specific and might not be portable across different database systems.

#### 4. Using a Counter in Poll

Add a counter in the `Poll` entity that keeps track of the number of choices. Each time a new choice is added, increment this counter and use it as the `choiceId`. This ensures that `choiceId` is unique per poll but resets for each new poll.

#### 5. Business Logic Layer

Handle the `choiceId` generation in your service layer or business logic layer, where you have more control over the ID generation logic. This would involve calculating the next `choiceId` based on the existing choices of a particular poll.

#### Choosing the Right Approach

Each of these approaches has its trade-offs in terms of complexity, ease of implementation, and maintainability. The best approach depends on your specific requirements and the environment in which your application operates.

For instance, if you want to keep things simple and avoid modifying the database schema, manual ID management or handling it at the business logic layer could be the way to go. On the other hand, if you need a more robust solution that scales well, considering a composite key or a database-level solution might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately, I went with a mix of 2. and 5. I used @IdClass annotation instead.

Answer (score 0):

The relation data bases just works this way. The Id must be unique for every record to distingt them. However if want to store collection with relation only to your poll you can try this way of setting field.

```
@Lob
@Column
private List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();
```

No need to make class Choise an Entity and no need to have Id at all, since you have indexed collection.